# Insert data using DB statement using Hash::make() of Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, hash

I would like insert data to DB using this query and a function Hash::make on Laravel, my code:

```
    $servidores = DB::select("INSERT INTO users ...
    SELECT
    ...
    CPF,
    ...
    FROM mdl0_servidores s
    join ...
```

Above works, but I'd like to use this:

```
...
Hash::make(CPF)
...
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the hash separately and include it into the query.

```php
$hash = Hash::make(CPF);

$servidores = DB::select("INSERT INTO users ...
    SELECT
    ...
    $hash,
    ...
    FROM mdl0_servidores s
    join ...
```

It is not advisable to use a raw query like this, but if you have to, you can use either string concatenation with `.` or the `$hash` with double-quotes to include the string into the query.

Comment: I am testing this

Comment: Din't work, returned this: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$2y$10$xiIrfIPuOgXl6ake3aKsm.nKCGw85yF703'`

Comment: You're using a `SELECT` when you're inserting – you probably should test on something smaller first, such as inserting a row without the hash.

Comment: Man, first thanks your attention!
The query works fine without the `$hash`, the `SELECT` is to get data from other table to insert. I'm using native query (`SELECT`) because is more fast then use a `foreach`. but perhaps you couldn't use viriable loop on native query. I dont know.

Comment: You can probably try the concatenation way, it could be the query string being problematic, i.e.: `DB::select("INSERT INTO..." . $hash . "... continuation";`. Also, you might want to check whether the sql is generated correctly with a toSql() at the end to get the raw query.